# SQL Server: Average per day of all months

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to display a line chart showing the days of the month from 1 to 31. The on the chart it needs to plot a line showing the average number of SMS credits used per day from all months.

My data looks like this:

```
**STATUS      StatusDate**
DELIVRD     2015-03-16 11:57:47.000
DELIVRD     2015-04-16 13:02:57.000
DELIVRD     2015-03-20 16:02:08.000
DELIVRD     2015-04-20 16:08:41.000
DELIVRD     2015-04-20 16:35:11.000
DELIVRD     2015-03-21 07:43:49.000
DELIVRD     2015-04-21 08:20:09.000
DELIVRD     2015-03-21 11:12:00.000
DELIVRD     2015-04-21 11:20:13.000
DELIVRD     2015-04-21 12:51:26.000
```

It needs to plot line showing the average count of the 16th of all months etc..

I'm using Entity Framework and C#.  The JQuery side is using ChartJS from the bootstrap admin theme.

This is what the result should look like:
[image]

Comment: Not really a SQL server question. Pick a reporting package (crystal reports, excel, etc) and use it

Comment: SQL server itself does not do charting. You need to write and application for that or use a reporting tool.

Comment: im developing this as a web application and we not using Crystal reports. I'm using the bootstrap theme with ChartJS.

Comment: Those were examples of things that can create reports, not endorsements or recommendations to use. Your question is having an identity crisis between being a SQLserver data-prep question and a chartjs output-like-x question.. **Please clean it up/ask 2 questions**

Comment: If I can get the SQL to pull the data as a table, then I can use C# to send the result back to JQuery as JSON and display the chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a query that will summarise your data by day, ready for feeding into your chosen reports package:

```
WITH t AS(
 SELECT
  CAST(statusdate as date) as da,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'DELIVRD' THEN 1 END) as count_delivered,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'FAILED' THEN 1 END) as count_failed -- or similar etc
 FROM
  your_table
 GROUP BY
  CAST(statusdate as date)
)

SELECT
  da,
  AVG(count_delivered),
  AVG(count_failed)
FROM
  t
GROUP BY
  da
```

Comment: This gives me the days separately.  I'm looking for all the 16ths as 1 average for all months. Will include a picture to illustrate this better.

Comment: I've edited my question to show what the result should look like

Comment: Only the 16ths? How will that draw the graph you depicted for other days not the 16th?

Comment: It needs to be for all days in the month, like how Rainman's answer is. Rainman's works well, gives me the average per day for all months of the same day. So all 1st of every month and so on. The point is to see which days of the month uses more credits.

Comment: remove the where clause that restricts it to the 16th (your question did say you wanted the average of all the 16ths of the month). Rainman's solution has a bug that makes it not what you asked for

Comment: After removing the where clause, I get the following error: 'Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.'

Comment: Did you accidentally also remove the GROUP BY when you removed the WHERE?

Comment: FYI: Rainmans works well. I've tried it and it gives me the exact result in SQL Server as I wanted. Thanks for your help anyways.

Comment: Have not removed the Group By

Comment: Apologies; made an error in the previous query, but should now be fixed

Comment: This is looking correct now. It's giving me the average count for the same day of every month.

Comment: The first part of the query counts all the SMS per day, on a  day/month/year basis, so e.g. the 2017-01-16 might be 50, and the 2017-02-16 might be 100, then the second part of the query AVG's that to 75.. If you just count them on the 16th you'll get "16th: 150" as a result. Note, if you don't charge for failed SMS/some statuses don't count, then should do some splitting based on the status as per here - it's what the CASE WHEN does, sorting the counts into different buckets based on the status. You could also do a `WHERE status IN ('DELIVRD', 'PENDING')` etc inside the `WITH( ...  )`

Comment: But the query still give you the each day for each month. Am i wrong ?

Comment: @Rainman, it gives me the each day of the month, but not the average for those days. Your answer was close, but it needs to display the average and not the count / sum.

Comment: I updated my answer. It calculates the average of each day of the month.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like that;

```
select DATEPART(DAY,StatusDateD) as [Day], AVG([count]) from (
select 
cast(StatusDate as date) as StatusDateD, 
count(*) as [count]
from Table
group by cast(StatusDate as date)
) Records group by DATEPART(DAY,StatusDateD)
order by [Day]
```

Comment: YES! this is what i'm looking for! :) Thank you.  Will try make a plan with your code. Thank you very much!

Comment: Have done so. Wow you was quick with your solution. Thank you again.

Comment: although your answer brings me close to my result. How can I get the average of the sum of credits on the same day? Currently you have it as count, so it's giving me the total for each day. Can I get it to show the average count for each day?

Comment: Yeah.. that's the bug that made it "not what you asked for" ;)